# When is a subgroup the Weil restriction of another subgroup?

Tags: algebraic-groups, ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157922/when-is-a-subgroup-the-weil-restriction-of-another-subgroup) on Math.StackExchange, to no avail. I try my chance on this one.

Let $M/F$ be an extension of fields. Let $G$ be an algebraic group over $F$, and consider the $F$-group $H$ defined as the restriction of scalars (a la Weil) of $G$ from $M$ down to $F$, i.e. $H=\mathrm{Res}_{M/F} G$. If $T$ is a subgroup of $H$, under what circumstances/hypotheses is it true that there exists a subgroup $\tilde{T}\leq G$ such that $T=\mathrm{Res}_{M/F} \tilde{T}$? Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't what went wrong with Latex...

Comment: Suppose that $M|F$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $A$. Then $H\times_F M\simeq \prod_{a\in A} G^a$, where $G$ is the twist of $G$ by $a$. The natural Galois action of $A$ on $H\times_F M$ is then given by the action by permutation on the right-hand side of the isomorphism. Thus a subgroup $T$ of $H$ corresponds to an $A$-invariant subgroup $T_1$ of $\prod_{a\in A} G^a$. In order for $T$ to be the Weil restriction of a subgroup $\widetilde{T}$, it is necessary and sufficient that $T_1\simeq \prod_{a\in A} G^a_1$, where $G_1$ is an subgroup of $G$ (defined over $M$). 


Comment: The above is very likely true for any finite field extension but then you have to work with descent data instead of Galois-equivariant objects.

Comment: @Damian Thank you. Do you have a reference for this? I find it very difficult to read the litterature on the restriction of scalars, on often-times, the results are buried deep into a sea of generalities.

Comment: @Damian: Your criterion can be simplified because $T$ is given over $F$: all one really needs to check is that $T_M$ decomposes as a direct product of subgroups of the various $G^a$'s (these factors are then automatically a Galois orbit, since $T$ was defined over $F$).  For example, this applies to all maximal $F$-tori and parabolic $F$-subgroups (assuming $G$ is smooth and connected).  Also, this works even if $M/F$ is just finite separable (not necessarily Galois), by using Galois descent from the Galois closure.

Comment: @quasi-coherent. I agree. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @M Turgeon. I don't have a direct reference for this; the best thing is to study the construction of the Weil restriction given in sec. 7.6 of the book "Néron Models" by Bosch et al.

Comment: Weil's original book "Adeles and algebraic groups" should be helpful to you, however it is difficult to get hold of a copy nowadays.

Comment: Thank you to everyone. @Damian I would suggest you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.